# The easiest way to pass multiple variable from 2 files html with Flask

Tags: python, variables, post, flask

I'm triyng to understand how Flask works.
I have this script running on my local machine:

```
@app.route('/ordini', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ordini():
    global data_start, ora_start, data_stop, id, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5

        if request.method == 'POST':

             id = request.form['id']
             data_start = request.form['data_start']
             ora_start = request.form['ora_start']
             data_stop = request.form['data_stop']

             M1 = request.form['M1']
             M2 = request.form['M2']
             M3 = request.form['M3']
             M4 = request.form['M4']
             M5 = request.form['M5']

             return render_template('ordine_macchine_necessarie.html',
                                    id=id, data_start=data_start, 
                                    data_stop=data_stop,                            
                                    ora_start=ora_start, 
                                    M1=M1, M2=M2, M3=M3, M4=M4, M5=M5)

return render_template('ordine.html')
```

Every thing works just fine, I get the values from the `ordine.html` and I pass them to `ordine_macchine_necessarie.html` but in my opinion I'm not passing the values in the correct way.
Do I really have to set all the variables like `id = request.form['id']` and then pass all of them like `id=id` ?
I can imagine forms composed by 50 or more values, I'm pretty sure that I'm not doing something correctly..

Maybe is better if I start to learn Django instad Flask? some users says that it is better!

Comment: You can pass the `request.form` dictionary or a copy of it to the template: `render_template ... data=request.form)` and within the template get the variables with `{{data["id"]}}` and the like.

Comment: @alessandrobuffoli also there is no need to have globals they are very liitle used in python if any, avoid keyword 'global' as much you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only specific fileds, you can do it like so:

```
             request_data = {
                 'id': request.form['id'],
                 'data_start': request.form['data_start'],
                 'ora_start': request.form['ora_start'],
                 'data_stop': request.form['data_stop'],
                 'M1': request.form['M1'],
                 'M2': request.form['M2'],
                 'M3': request.form['M3'],
                 'M4': request.form['M4'],
                 'M5': request.form['M5'],
             }

             # or dicitionary comprehension
             # relevant_keys = ['id','data_start','ora_start','data_stop', 'M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5']
             # requst_data = {key: request.form[key] for key in relevant_keys}

             return render_template('ordine_macchine_necessarie.html', **request_data)
```

If you want all the data from form you do this:

```
 return render_template('ordine_macchine_necessarie.html', **request.form)
```

As of Flask/Tornado/aiohttp/Falcon they are all good to know, before you go into Django, it is worth to at least write some small project with them.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, but instead if i need to get all fields? how can i do it?

Comment: @alessandrobuffoli hey i'we updated my answer, hope it helps, regards.

Comment: Thankyou, you are really great, I'm triyng right now, but i can't have a success result.
to get all the results do I have to declare the variables name somewhere? like id, data_start.. 
because if i just write `return render_template('ordine_macchine_necessarie.html', **request.form)` nothing happen

Comment: @alessandrobuffoli it is hard to know without more code, how does your 'ordine_macchine_necessarie.html' looks like? Do you get any errors?

Comment: i figure it out, I had som errors in the `ordine_macchine_necessarie.html`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get all keyword from form and values, I think that you can use:
`do_something(**request.form`)

Edit: Your current code would be adapted like that:

```
@app.route('/ordini', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ordini():

    if request.method == 'POST':

         return render_template('ordine_macchine_necessarie.html',**request.form)

return render_template('ordine.html')
```

The documentation says that `request.form` is an `ImmutableMultiDict`.

> By default an ImmutableMultiDict is returned from this function. This can be changed by setting parameter_storage_class to a different type. This might be necessary if the order of the form data is important.
>   http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.form

And if you look at the `MultiDict` documentation, you can see that you can use any dictionary methods. I guess you can use the kwargs syntax.

> A MultiDict is a dictionary subclass customized to deal with multiple values for the same key which is for example used by the parsing functions in the wrappers. This is necessary because some HTML form elements pass multiple values for the same key.
>
> MultiDict implements **all standard dictionary methods**. Internally, it saves all values for a key as a list, but **the standard dict access methods will only return the first value for a key**. If you want to gain access to the other values, too, you have to use the list methods as explained below
>   http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict